# Where exactly do they move to in the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, away-we-go

In the movie [*Away We Go*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1176740/) the couple travels all around the US, and finally they find a home that they feel suits them.

They pass a tree with strange fruit on it, like in her story of her childhood home. However, when they go inside, she seems to behave like she's never been inside the house before.

Where is the viewer supposed to understand they have ended up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They ended up in Verona's childhood home. As they drive up I believe she even says that it's as beautiful as she remembers it. I think when she goes inside, she's supposed to be behaving as if she hasn't been there in years (as her parents died when she was 22 and hasn't been there in a long time). Perhaps the the choices the actress made to portray that were confusing.

Comment: Ok, I guess that makes sense then. It never actually says where her childhood home _is_, does it. But in that case, who stuck the fruit on the tree?

Comment: I always assumed it was Burt, trying to make the place as much as he could like she remembered it